# How to use Reflection if the the Bean class contains Array of class?

Tags: java, arrays, object, reflection

The below bean class contains the array of class which is a multivalued attribute.I am trying to dynamically set values to the attributes below using Reflection.

```
public class User {

    private String userId;
    private NameDetails[] nameDetails;
    private ContactDetails contactDetails;

    public ContactDetails getContactDetails() {
        return contactDetails;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }      

    public void setContactDetails(ContactDetails contactDetails) {
        this.contactDetails = contactDetails;
    }

    public NameDetails[] getNameDetails() {
        return nameDetails;
    }

    public void setNameDetails(NameDetails[] nameDetails) {
        this.nameDetails = nameDetails;
    } 
}
```

The below code is where we implement reflection and I am not able to set a value to the array.

```
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(method.getReturnType().getComponentType().getName());
        Object arr = Array.newInstance(c, 1);
        Method method = innerFieldType.getMethod("set" + tokens[i], arr.getClass());
        Object obj = Array.get(arr, 0);
        Array.set(obj, 0, finalRefObject);
        method.invoke(finalRefObject, Array.get(arr, 0));
```

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: array element type mismatch"

is the error we get.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please fix your indentation

Comment: Why are you doing Class.forName instead of just `method.getReturnType().getComponentType()`?

Comment: We need to get the class and return type